# A problem with generic method overloading

Tags: c#, generics, methods, overloading

I have the following methods:

```
void s<t>(int a, t b)
{
    ...
    ..
    .
}

void s<int>(int a, int b)
{
    ...
    ..
    .
}

void s<long>(int a, long b)
{
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

when I want to use it as `s<long>(10,10)` I see these overrides in tooltip. 
`s<long>(int a,int b);` **and**  `s<long>(int a,long b);`. But, I think i must see just `s<long>(int a,long b);`.

What's wrong ? I have *visual studio 2008 sp1*.

Thanks

**Update :** I have test it in Visual Studio 2010.The result is the same.
**Update :** It seems it is about c# not visual studio.

Comment: `int`s can be automatically promoted to `long`s, so this is correct behaviour.

Comment: These aren't overrides - they're overloads. And you don't declare generic methods like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to provide the type parameters you want in the generic definition directly, which is not going to work. If you wish to have versions of the method that support (for the second parameter) objects of type `int, long, and T`, declare 2 non-generic method overloads and one generic.

```
void S(int a, int b)
void S(int a, long b)
void S<T>(int a, T b)
```

Overload resolution will then call the appropriate method based on the arguments, matching the non-generic versions for exact matches on `int` or `long` (you *can* get the generic version even with a `int` or `long` parameter if you explicitly invoke it using a type parameter), otherwise getting the generic version.

Examples:

```
void S<T>(int a, T b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("generic method");
}

void S(int a, int b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("int overload");
}

void S(int a, long b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("long overload");
}
```

...

```
S(10, 10);
S(10, (long)10);
S(10, 10L);
S(10, 10M);
S<int>(10, 10); // uses generic
S<long>(10, 10); // uses generic & implicit conversion
```

**Edit:** To expand upon a point mentioned briefly above and further in the comments, the match for the `int` and `long` overloads needs to be ***exact.*** All other arguments will result in the selection of the generic version. If you *do not have an int* but *want the int overload*, you will need to explicitly convert the argument prior to or during the method invocation. ex: `S(10, (int)myShort);`.

Similarly, if you have two versions of method `C`

```
void C(Mammal m) { }
void C<T>(T t) { }
```

with

```
class Tiger : Mammal { }
```

The invocation `C(new Tiger())` will result in the generic method being used. If you want the `Mammal` overload for the `Tiger` instance, you need a reference via the base class. Such as

```
Mammal m = new Tiger();
C(m); // uses mammal overload
// or 
Tiger t = new Tiger();
C((Mammal)t); // uses mammal overload
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but you still have to be a bit careful. Suppose you call S(10, myShort), for example. Which is better, the generic, the int, or the long version? Many people expect that "short goes to int, so the int version is better", but in fact the right answer is that S<short> matches *exactly* and the int and long versions are inexact matches, so the generic version wins.