# overloading with generics. Is it expected behaviour?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A problem with generic method overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093112/a-problem-with-generic-method-overloading)

Here is a simple code:

```
static class Example  
{  
    static int DoIt(object o) { return 0; }    
    class A { }
    static int DoIt(A a) { return 1; }
    static int CallDoIt<X>(X x) { return DoIt(x); }
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = new A();
        System.Console.WriteLine(DoIt(a));      // returns 1 (as desired)
        System.Console.WriteLine(CallDoIt(a));  // returns 0
    }
}
```

The result looks very strange: the function DoIt() called directly returns different value from the case when it is called from another function. Is it expected behaviour in C#? If yes, how to achieve the desired behaviour (preferably without reflection)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour, the knowledge of what type `X` is does not extend into the `CallDoIt` function. The overload of `DoIt` called from `CallDoIt` is determined statically based on the type of the argument `x`. Since `X` can be anything, the best (and only) candidate is `DoIt(object)`.

You can get around this behaviour by delaying the dispatch to `DoIt` until runtime using dynamic:

```
static int CallDoIt<X>(X x) { return DoIt((dynamic)x); }
```

The other alternative is to provide a more specific version of `CallDoIt`:

```
static int CallDoIt(A a) { return DoIt(a); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Method call `DoIt(x)` inside method `CallDoIt<X>(X x)` must work for any `X` type, so C# compiler chose to use `DoIt(object o)` overload.
If you restrict `X` type to derive from type `A` like this:

```
static int CallDoIt<X>(X x) where X : A { return DoIt(x); }
```

Then C# compiler will know it can chose `DoIt(A a)` overload since `X` type will always derive from type `A`. This also answers your second question of how to achieve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the expected behaviour. A generic method is compiled once for all possible arguments. During that single compilation, `DoIt(x)` cannot be resolved to `DoIt(A)`, so it is `DoIt(object)`, and that is what it will always be.

You can dynamically check the object type, or better yet, have .NET Framework do so for you:

```
static int CallDoIt(object x) { return DoIt((dynamic)x); }
```

Note that there is no benefit here to making `CallDoIt` generic: it would do exactly the same as this version. That means that `CallDoIt((object)a)` calls `DoIt(A)`, *not* `DoIt(object)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using dynamic does resolves the problem.My concern is that this C# behaviour is error prone.

Comment: In a more complicated case, at the time of writing the method CallDoIt<X>() one might not be interested in the implementation of DoIt() (in fact, this implementation may be changed later on). It seems that calling overloaded methods from generics is in general dangerous. Is it correct?

Comment: @user2016189 This is one of the fundamental differences between C# generics and C++ templates. In a C++ template, the equivalent of your code would call the `DoIt(A)` overload. I don't know if you're familiar with the problems of putting C++ templates in libraries, but if you're not, generics solve a big problem at a fairly minor inconvenience, because as it turned out, the need for template specialisations / overloads is relatively low.

Comment: @user2016189 It's a design choice, I guess: if `DoIt((object)a)` and `DoIt(a)` do different things, perhaps they shouldn't have the same name? If such functions are named differently, you're not dealing with overloaded functions, and you don't face the problem you're having now.

Comment: Note also that this kind of "bugs" are not caught neither on compile nor on run time.

Comment: Regarding "the problems of putting C++ templates in libraries". No, I am not sure what you mean. Would appreciate if you give me some idea (or a link).

Comment: On the other hand, the indicated behaviour is explained by the fact that C# resolves that in compile time and a "generic method is compiled once for all possible arguments". C++ also resolves templates in compile time, but but selects an appropriate overloads for each call according to the template parameter. Why doesn't C# do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Add another overload for CallDoIt:

```
static int CallDoIt(A x) { return DoIt(x); }
```

This will make things work.

Answer (score 0):

The overload resolution occurs at compile time (if no dynamic resolution needed) and most specific type for `X`(type parameter) is `object`.

Answer (score 0):

The decision of choose calling method will be resolved at compile time. The C# compiler does not know what is the type X and choosed the method with DoIt(object o).